# Using JavaScript to hit web service running in Azure

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, azure

I have an Azure ASP.Net web role running my web UI.  I have an MvC4 REST API running in a separate web role in the same Azure instance.  Azure puts the web UI on port 80 and the API on port 8080.  So when I want to send an AJAX request from a web page to the REST API, I need to munge the URL to change the port to connect to the REST API instead of the web UI web role.

I have this JavaScript in my page:

```
    function getWebAPIURL(criteria) {
      //      The generated code had this:
      //        var uri = 'api/values';
      //  But that only works if the API is running in the same Azure web role as the UI,
      //  which it isn't - it's running in the same domain but on port 8080.  So we have
      //  to munge the URL a bit to get the correct URL for the RESTful API

      var strWebAPIURL =    window.location.protocol + '://' +
                            window.location.hostname + ':8080' +
                            '/api/values';

      // If provided,critiera is appended in REST style, e.g api/values/5
      if (criteria != undefined && criteria != null && criteria != '') {
          strWebAPIURL = strWebAPIURL + '/' + criteria;
      }
      // console.log(strWebAPIURL);
      return strWebAPIURL;
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
      // Send an AJAX request
      $.getJSON(getWebAPIURL())
          .done(function (data) {
              // On success, 'data' contains a list of files.
              $('#File').text(formatReturnedItems(data));
          });
  });
```

When I stop in the debugger, I see that the URL returned from getWebAPIURL is (correctly, I believe)

```
http://xxxx.cloudapp.net:8080/api/values
```

But I get back a 404 error from the getJSON call.  When I look at Fiddler, I see that the URL is apparently going to

[image: Fiddler Output]

i.e. it's continuing to use the **main domain** as the base and taking my xxxx.cloudapp.net:8080 as a sub-part of the URL.  I believe this has something to do with the prevention against cross-domain calls.

But this seems like a very common case - I have a web UI and an API layer that is REST.  It doesn't seem like I'm trying to do something really bizarre here that should be hard - so I have the feeling I'm just doing something simple wrong.

Hoe do others do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.protocol` will return the protocol with a trailing colon ([ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_protocol.asp)). Therefore there isn't any need to include it in your JavaScript.

```
var strWebAPIURL = window.location.protocol + '//' +
                   window.location.hostname + ':8080' +
                   '/api/values';
```

The above code will create a valid URL so that the jQuery `$.getJSON()` function doesn't feel the need to change it.

Comment: For lack of a nail... this was the problem.  I didn't look closely enough to see that the URL in fact had an extra ":"... Overthinking the problem.  Thanks!